# Cloning using pET28a and Protein Expression in DH5alpha and BL21

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, cloning, protein-expression, vector

Can someone please direct me to an e-resource or a book that will help a newbie like me learn in depth about Cloning using pET28a and Protein Expression in DH5alpha and BL21. Though I have done cloning using TA vectors, pET28a is very new to me. I need to design primers with restriction sites to insert my GOI into pET28a, so would like to learn how to choose these sites too.

Comment: Did you try google? The pET28 systems manual and plasmid maps are easy to track down. 
https://research.fhcrc.org/content/dam/stripe/hahn/methods/biochem/pet.pdf
https://www.addgene.org/vector-database/2565/

Comment: I did come across these, but they don't answer questions like how the choice of restriction sites will influence your protein. A fellow researcher was asked to justify his choice of restriction sites. If I remember correctly he had used a combination of SacI and HindIII for which a review a reviewer suggested replacing the SacI site as it might cause non-specific proteins to be expressed. It has something to do with codons, but I am not too sure, hence the query!

Comment: I can't think of a reason this would matter for this plasmid specifically. It's possible they were concerned about potential coding regions adjacent to your gene of interest, especially if it contained something like a promoter or an extra start codon. If your colleague sequenced their construct, it should be easy enough to spot any unwanted elements upstream of your GOI.

Comment: Thanks, i'll read more about this.